# Use Connectify to share VPN to my iPhone

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn, iphone, connectify

I'm trying to share the VPN used on my PC to my iPhone by [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/).

Now the problem is: in the first few seconds after the WiFi set up by Connectify started, 
my iPhone can connect to Twiter and YouTube (now you know I'm in China, so I need the VPN).

But, then (about 10 seconds after WiFi started) my iPhone can only connect to those websites which is not firewalled in China.

Can anybody tell me how to solve this problem so I can use my VPN via my iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as yours. What I ended with was that this is the problem of connectify (it can be some conflicts with your wireless adapter and connectify too).
You can try other alternatives to Connectify but I dont think they can help.
I think its best to not waste time on it, instead try to connect to vpn inside the iphone.